# Sculpting by "One click" instead of moving slightly the mouse? (Custom Brushes)

Tags: sculpting

I have a basic problem which I can't find it, it's a custom brush created by other person.

The problem is, I can't sculpt with this brush by clicking but I have to move the mouse to sculpt. How do I change this?

Also, this person in his preview gif showed that he could sculpt by clicking, but I can't do it...

Comment: As a wild guess maybe there is enabled Smooth Stroke in the brush settings > Stroke

Comment: No, there wasn't Smooth Stroke. Here's the page where you can see the gif. https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/69653. I don't know if I can give link, but it would be useful to refer what I want, sculpt by clicking.